# Cannot mount drive on-premises - Azure file storage over VPN

Tags: windows, azure, azure-files

I am trying to mount a drive on my local on-premises Windows 10 pro machine (SMB 3.0).

I setup my Vnet in Azure, my Vnet gateway (P2S VPN) and shared file storage account.

The usual way to mount the drive is to use the NET USE commnand such as :

```
net use [drive letter] \\xxx.file.core.windows.net\fileshare /u:user [Password key]
```

If I run the NET USE command on a VM it mounts the drive instantly without a problem.

However, running the command from the on-premises Windows 10 pro machine I get the `System error 53 has occurred` error message.

I know that this error is often due to the fact that the ISP blocks port 445. However, my understanding is that this should not be a problem if I setup and use the P2S VPN. Doesn't the VPN bypass the ISP restrictions ?

I have tested the VPN and connectivity is confirmed.

I've also turned off all firewalls (PC and router) while trying to do this.

When the VPN is connected I try to ping the public IP address of the Vnet but this times out. I have read that Azure does block these ICMP pings.

I have also tried a tracert to my `xxx.file.core.windows.net` and it does timeout after 5 hops.

Am I trying to do something that cannot be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure, we **can't** use P2S VPN mount file share to your local PC. Because file share service work on the Internet, and we can't force the file share network traffic through P2S/S2S vpn.

As a workaround, we can deploy a **RRAS VPN**  on Azure VM, and use local PC to connect the RRAS server, after connected, the local PC will get an IP from Azure datacenter, so we can mount file share on you local PC.

Here a blog about how to deploy RRAS on azure VM, please refer to [it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/notime/2013/06/01/how-to-setup-windows-azure-server-2012-as-an-sstp-and-l2tp-vpn-provider/).

Comment: Please let me know if you would like further assistance

Comment: Jason, thank you so much for your help, Truly appreciated ! 

I have done all of the steps in the blog but when I try to connect my VPN I get the "Error 0x800B0109 : A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate,,," message. 

This is usually because the certificate was not imported in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store. 

I have checked and on the client machine it is in that store. On the server side, I selected that certificate in the RRAS security tab of my server under SSL certificate binding (HTTP not ticked). 

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MikeA  please follow this blob to set site bingdings, To verify certificates, open `Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager` on the Server Essentials, and click to open **Bindings** for the **Default Web Site**.https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sbs/2014/06/11/troubleshooting-common-vpn-issues-on-windows-server-2012-r2-essentials/

Comment: Thank you so much, I am now able to connect to my Azure Server VM using VPN. I solved the certificate problem by purchasing a cheap SSL certicicate (about $6) and once installed on client and server side all worked. I am now having issues with not being able to connect to shared folder on server via VPN but will post separate question if needed. Thanks for all your help !